# SSIS how can i insert a blank date to database with visual basic

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, ssis

how can i insert a blank date to sql database in ssis working with a visual basic script component?
I have to transfer date from excel to database and i would like to insert a blank or null value in the database if in the excel is empty

thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the script component, create a new output column - of type `DATE`.  This will expose it in the object model in the script as a writable object - There will be a `Row.COLUMNNAME` for the value and `Row.COLUMNNAME_IsNull`.  Presumably your input column is coming in as a string column.

Then in the script, set `Row.COLUMNNAME_IsNull = True` when appropriate conditions are met, e.g (this is production code, with a `preCOMPDATE` string column coming from the source, and a `COMPDATE` date column in the output):

```
If Row.preCOMPDATE_IsNull Then
    ' In this example we only set it to NULL is the string is null - you might also do this for blanks or whatever else the string might contain
    Row.COMPDATE_IsNull = True
Else
    ' This is a date cleansing routine defined elsewhere in the script - out of range dates are defaulted to 1/1/1900, among other things, logging errors and setting severities
    Row.COMPDATE = ValidateDate("COMPDATE", _
                                Row.preCOMPDATE, _
                                startDate, _
                                endDate, _
                                New Date(1900, 1, 1), _
                                ErrorDesc, _
                                IsRegDtError)
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

By blank do you mean default date, or keeping it NULL??

Instead of inserting a blank date into SQl Server, could you not just set up a default date in the SQL Table itself, so that it automatically does it if nothing is passed to that field?

Comment: I have to transfer date from excel to database and i would like to insert a blank or null value in the database if in the excel is empty